# Not a legitimate tree

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
> head(main)
  X MYDEPV Price Income Age price20 price30
1 1      1    10     33  37       0       0
2 2      0    20     21  55       1       0
```

I am trying to prune a decision tree in R. I am getting the error "not a legitimate tree." What does this error mean? What is a legitimate tree? How do I fix this?

```
> tree <- rpart(MYDEPV ~ Price + Income + Age, main, method="class", parms = list(split = "gini"))
> tree = prune.tree(tree)
Error in prune.tree(tree) : not legitimate tree
```

Comment: That function is from **tree**, not **rpart**.

Comment: try ..., "data = main", instead "main"

Comment: Illegitimate trees are saplings from non-mahoganous relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use

```
prune.rpart()
```

rather than prune.tree()

The error "Not a legitimate tree" stems from the fact that prune.tree() is not expecting a object of class "rpart" which is what you have created in the previous line.

prune.tree requires a object of class "tree", and as was stated in the comments is from the tree package, not the rpart package.